# Appending a full array to other arrays in a for loop, similar to appending to a list (python)?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a function that returns an array, and I want to keep calling that function with a different parameter, and then keep appending the resulting array over the course of a for loop. Right now, I just define a list and add the new array to the list, and then stack it all at the end. That seems very inefficient.

Here's an example: here I just defined an array with the numpy random.rand  to show the type of array that should be returned and then appended.

```
import numpy as np
total = 3
rows = 3
my_list = []
for i in range(total):
    output_array = np.random.rand(rows,2) # this could be variable
    my_list.append(output_array)

final_array = np.vstack(my_list)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this, such that I can just append directly to the array and get the final full array at the end? The issue is that I don't know the pre-determined number of times I'll loop over the list, so I can't use concatenation, etc.

Comment: Why do you think the list append is inefficient?  Do you understand how things are added to a list?  Or that arrays can't grow in the same way?

Comment: "Right now, I just define a list and add the new array to the list, and then stack it all at the end. That seems very inefficient." No, that is actually the *efficient way of doing this*. You cannot `.append` to an array in-place, it is *an array* not a list. So `numpy.ndarray.append` creates *a new array*, but that forces you to use a quadratic time algorithm. Your list approach is linear time.

Comment: @Pygirl that is exactly equivalent to what they are doing already...

Comment: @hpaulj: No I didn't say list append if efficient. I just gave a suggestion to make it more pythonic. I can't think of any improvement for this one as itertools.chain will not optimize. I guess this is fine.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I just wanted to make it more pythonic :(. I don't see any improvement.  I can only think of `itertools.chain` if memory is an issue.

Comment: @Pygirl, in practice the function that creates the array is likely to be complex enough that the time difference between an append loop and a list comprehension will be minor. The OP is looking for something that 'grows' an array with better efficiency (there isn't).

Answer (score 1):

Lists are designed for efficient appending, storing objects by reference in a buffer with growth room.

Arrays only grow by making a new array, requiring a full copy.  That's best done once on a whole list.  Iterative concatenate requires a lot more copying.

But feel free to do your own time tests.